# Why I cant override checked out items in list being Site collection admin

Tags: 2013, list, permissions

One of the user in my organization wants to get rid of a excel document in SharePoint list. Unfortunately the file is checked out by his colleague and he is out for a month. User wants to discard check out and delete the document. For some reason Discard check out option is disabled. Farm administrator also don't have right to undo the checkout. File is locked out, how do I undo checkout, I thought we had that option available who has full control permissions in SharePoint sites.

Comment: Are you trying this from SPD or from Browser?